# PayPal - how to set auto return on sandbox?

Tags: paypal, return

I have read that for enabling the auto return I have to enable this functionality on www.paypal.com - but how to enable auto return in sandbox mode?

Comment: What is 'auto return' mean? Do you want to take user back to your website after payment success or fail? What PayPal method are you using?

Comment: yes, exactly. I use web payment (standard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to provide `return` url and `cancel_return` url when you post to PayPal.

More details of the variable are [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)